# Javascript quick way to have many classes in multiple files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am thinking how to make things simple with many Javascript classes. I want to use separate files, otherwise I get more than 1000 rows file. I am now splitting it.

Earlier in one file it was one function jQuery document ready and inside were defined classes. So global space is not polluted.

When I split into files, I only think of using some one object which holds those classes, like this:

```
globalobject = {

};

globalobject.class1 = {
    // code
}

globalobject.class2 = {
    // code
}
```

But I hate having to write `globalobject.classname`. Everything looked nicer in one file.

Another option would be to use prefixes like pre_class1, pre_class2 but its also not the ideal.

Maybe there somehow can help requirejs, but I took quick look, but did not find how can I quickly use it, I have never used it before, and it does not look so quick when not used before.

Any suggestions? Btw I am also using backbone with marionette, but I am very new to marionette. I have seen it also has some modules, but still it would not be a quick way yet for me.

Or should I not even try to split the long file until I haven't understood marionette modules or requirejs library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `extend` method of underscore to add the functions to your base class:

```
// file1
var object = {
  foo : function () {...}
}

_.extend(object, objectFromFile2);

// file2
var objectFromFile2 = {
  bar : function () {...}
}
```

You now have `object.foo` and `object.bar`

If your actual question was "How do I get the code from file1 into file2" I would recommend looking at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I stared looking at requireJS, somehow, every way suggested did not look perfect. Maybe the first anwswer with globalObject was good but had errors at that moment when I tried so thats why also trying requireJS :) proably sooner or later I will need to understand it anyway

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
globalobject = (function(globalobject) {

  // common code only accessible from class1 and inside this closure

  var class1 = {
      //code
  };

  globalobject.class1 = class1;

  return globalobject;

}) ( globalobject || {} );
```

This way will make it possible to have one "class" in each file, and works regardless of the order of import when adding several "classes" to the globalobject.

Comment: You can also rename the argument to the anonymous function to something like "container".

Comment: gets error in line } ( globalobject || {} ); Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep reusing the `globalobject` notation.

You can do:

```
// define the class in local scope
function MyClass() {};
MyClass.prototype.myFunction = function () {};
MyClass.prototype.myOtherFunction = function () {};

// then export it
globalobject.MyClass = MyClass;
```

Comment: Is local scope eguals to global object?

Comment: It means that perhaps you're creating `MyClass` function in global object but one who using it is another object ?